# What is the ViewStub inside DecorView?

Tags: android, viewstub

I found that under `decorView`, with or without title or `ActionBar`, `ViewStub` would exist.

What's the use of it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basing on id of this view its is probably place/space/container for [`ActionMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html) layout. On some devices it may look like below (top bar above content, when `ActionBar`/`Toolbar` present then is replaced)

[image: action mode example]

Comment: What is the specific, I feel you did not say clearly ah！

Comment: from doc: `A ViewStub is an invisible, zero-sized View that can be used to lazily inflate layout resources at runtime`. When your `Activity` enter into `ActionMode` then new layout is inflated and placed in `action_mode_bar_stub` `ViewStub`s place. You have a screen above on which you can see action bar mode (bar with "Aufgabe" text, share, bin icon etc.) already inflated into this viewstub/container. In this case it have width/height > 0

Answer (score 1):

[`ViewStub`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) is kind of a `View`, that would be lazily inflated at a later time when needed.

In the graph you have you posted you can see `action_mode_bar_stub` id.

Clearly, it's not always that you would actually need that view to be inflated. You would only need that once user enters [Contextual Action Mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu). Thus, in order not to convolute the view hierarchy, that view would not be inflated until user would actually need that view to be displayed. Once inflated, view hierarchy would change and you no longer will see that `ViewStub` there.

Comment: I know that this is a dynamically loaded layout, but just do not know the role of this layout on here. Because I found that whenever I print it wide and high, it was 0.

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. It seems to me the answer clarifies *"the role"* of that layout.

Comment: @Nevermore it will be 0 when `Activity` isn't in `ActionMode` (by default ofc). when you enter in `ActionMode` then action-layout will be inflated and placed in this container, then it will have non-zero height/width

Answer (score 0):

Look at this file: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/6bebb8418ceecf44d2af40033870f3aabacfe36e/core/res/res/layout/screen.xml

In this file, the actual code for `action_mode_bar_stub`:

```
<!-- Popout bar for action modes -->
<ViewStub android:id="@+id/action_mode_bar_stub"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/action_mode_bar"
    android:layout="@layout/action_mode_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"/>
```

There is says that it is the popout bar for action modes.